# Magento 2.3 - Add custom customer entity attribute with service contract

Tags: customer-attribute, eav, service-contract

I have some problem to save custom customer entity attribute in database.
I've created a Patch to add this attribute to the customer entity. The attribute is shown correctly in the backend, but when I try to save it, the value doesn't save in the database.

My code is the following:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Ped\Referral\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

class AddCustomerReferralCodeAttribute implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $attributeRepository;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeRepositoryInterface $attributeRepository,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @return DataPatchInterface|void
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $this->removeReferralCodeAttribute();
        $this->addReferralCodeAttribute();
    }

    /**
     * Remove referral_code customer attribute
     */
    private function removeReferralCodeAttribute()
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'referral_code');
    }

    /**
     * Add referral_code customer attribute
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException
     */
    private function addReferralCodeAttribute()
    {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            'referral_code',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Referral Code',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 999,
                'position' => 999,
                'visible' => true,
                'default' => '',
                'user_defined' => true,
                'system' => 0,
                'unique' => true,
            ]
        );

        $referralCodeAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()
            ->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'referral_code')
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
            ]);

        $this->attributeRepository->save($referralCodeAttribute);
    }
}
```

If I replace `$this->attributeRepository->save($referralCodeAttribute);` with `$referralCodeAttribute->save()` all works properly, but I don't want to use the `save()` method of attribute entity, because is deprecated.

I know that now I should use the resource model/api interface to save attribute, but in both cases, the attribute is showing on the admin panel, but when I try to save, it doesn't work. Why?

How can I use the resource model/api interface correctly to save the custom attribute?

Comment: did you try using `Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface` ?

Comment: No, I will try it and I'll say you if it works

Comment: I have modified your code, please check and let me know if it works or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution by dump the ResourceModel classname used by the `save()` method that was deprecated in favor of service contract. The resource model that I should used is `Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute`. Here the complete code:

```
<?php    
namespace Ped\Referral\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute as AttributeResourceModel;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;

class AddCustomerReferralCodeAttribute implements DataPatchInterface
{
    private const REFERRAL_CODE_FIELD_NAME = 'referral_code';

    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeResourceModel
     */
    private $attributeResourceModel;

    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        AttributeResourceModel $attributeResourceModel
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeResourceModel = $attributeResourceModel;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType(Customer::ENTITY);
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            static::REFERRAL_CODE_FIELD_NAME,
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Referral Code',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 999,
                'position' => 999,
                'visible' => true,
                'default' => '',
                'user_defined' => true,
                'system' => 0,
                'unique' => true,
            ]
        );

        $referralCodeAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()
            ->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, static::REFERRAL_CODE_FIELD_NAME)
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
            ]);

        $this->attributeResourceModel->save($referralCodeAttribute);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one using `Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface`:

```
<?php
/*declare(strict_types=1);*/

namespace Ped\Referral\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
//add this AttributeSetRepositoryInterface
use Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface;

class AddCustomerReferralCodeAttribute implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $attributeRepository;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var $attribute
     */
    private $attribute;


    /**
     * AddCustomerReferralCodeAttribute constructor.
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeRepositoryInterface $attributeRepository
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetRepositoryInterface $attribute
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeRepositoryInterface $attributeRepository,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetRepositoryInterface $attribute
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->attribute = $attribute;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @return DataPatchInterface|void
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $this->removeReferralCodeAttribute();
        $this->addReferralCodeAttribute();
    }

    /**
     * Remove referral_code customer attribute
     */
    private function removeReferralCodeAttribute()
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'referral_code');
    }

    /**
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    private function addReferralCodeAttribute()
    {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            'referral_code',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Referral Code',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 999,
                'position' => 999,
                'visible' => true,
                'default' => '',
                'user_defined' => true,
                'system' => 0,
                'unique' => true,
            ]
        );

        $referralCodeAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()
            ->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'referral_code')
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
            ]);

        //$this->attributeRepository->save($referralCodeAttribute);
        $this->attribute->save($referralCodeAttribute);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work, I receive this error: "Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Eav\Model\AttributeSetRepository\Interceptor::save() must implement interface Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeSetInterface, instance of Magento\Customer\Model\Attribute given, called in /var/www/html/app/code/Ped/Referral/Setup/Patch/Data/AddCustomerReferralCodeAttribute.php on line 138 and defined in /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Eav/Model/AttributeSetRepository/Interceptor.php:20"